# Jest tests not working after moving to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Recently I've moved a project from plain old JavaScript to TypeScript. Previously every test was running fine. Right after the change some test cases just broke and I can not understand why. I'm using Vue.js alongside `vue-test-utils` and `jest`.

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '/src/**/*.{js,jsx,vue}',
        '!**/node_modules/**',
        '!**/vendor/**',
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'ts',
        'js',
        'json',
        'vue',
    ],
    transform: {
        '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
        '^.+\\.ts$': 'ts-jest',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!vuex-class-modules).+\\.js$',
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
    ],
};
```

A snippet of an example test that's failing right now, which has been working fine previously.

**some.test.js**

```
function mountStore(loggedInState) {
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
            customer: {
                namespaced: true,
                state: {
                    isLoggedIn: loggedInState,
                },
                actions,
            },
        },
    });

    return shallowMount(Component, {
        localVue,
        store,
        router,
        stubs: { 'router-link': RouterLinkStub },
    });
}

describe('Test with customer logged in at beginning', () => {
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mountStore(true);
    });

    it('should redirect to home if user is logged in on init', () => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.$route.name).toBe('Home');
    });
});
```

Regarding this specific test case, the result is as following.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "Home"
Received: null
```

I also noticed upgrading all dependencies (including some Jest dependencies) leads to even more failing tests. So I expect that to (probably) be the reason, since I just added TypeScript support later on. However, I don't know what dependency combination would lead to a faulty behavior.

Relevant dependencies I've updated, which eventually would lead to even more failing tests.

- jest
- ts-jest
- babel-jest

Comment: Since there are no compiler errors, I don't think that TS itself has to be blamed. Better focus on changes that were made when you "moved a project from plain old JavaScript to TypeScript". "So I expect that to (probably) be the reason, since I just added TypeScript support later on" - then that's it, downgrade them first.

Comment: @Aer, I am facing the same issue. Did you come across any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-babel',
```

to `jest.config.js` since you use `ts-jest` with `babel-jest`. [Source](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/#jest-preset).

Comment: Doesn't do anything. Still the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue.  @winwiz1's answer worked for me, but I needed to put it inside the project definition as I'm using the projects syntax.  I would just leave this as a comment on @winwiz1's answer, but StackOverflow mangles the format.

```
projects: [
    {
      "displayName": "test-unit",
      "preset": "ts-jest",
      "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/test-unit/**/*\\.tests\\.[t|j]s"]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding `@types/jest`? And adding it in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"types": ["@types/node", "@nuxt/types", "@types/jest", "nuxt-i18n"]
```

Comment: Yes, they are included. However, I don't get any type errors. The test just fails. I've updated my question accordingly.